# How to Maintain logged in state of user in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I am currently in the process of implementing state management for a web application that we have developed using ExtJS4.

For example, in Ext.application, I wrote:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
Ext.Component.prototype.stateful = false;
```

On whichever control should maintain its state, we made the `stateful` property of that control `true`. In the below example, the stateful property of the combobox is true and working fine (these states will be used for the subsequent logged-in user):

```
{
    xtype: 'combo'
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'myid'
}
```

Now I would like to know if there is a way to maintain state on the same machine based on the user logged in. For example, when user1 logs in and logs out the value selected in a combobox is 10, and when user2 logs in and logs out the value selected in the combobox is 20.

I would like to maintain the state in such a way that when user1 is re-logged in, the combo box should show 10 and for user2, the combo box should show 20. Is it possible to maintain state on a per-user basis, not for the whole application (machine basis)?

Thanks & Regards,
Mani Kumar Y

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to adjust the `stateId` based on the current user, such as `stateId: username + '-myid'`. That way when "user1" is logged in, the stateId is `user1-myid`, and when user2 is logged in, the stateId is `user2-myid`. In that way, the states can be stored and loaded separately, depending on the current user.

Comment: interesting suggestion. wonder if anyone tried this. also wonder why there are still computers shared by multiple users ... other than shop floor I guess.